# WordPress page with slider and dynamic content

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to make a "catalog" of equipment in WordPress, it should look like the one at the picture. I've already created a slider with images and description for all of my items, the slider works fine.

Now when I click the next/prev arrows I select some item and **I need to set the text content on the page with the selected item's data.**

How can I handle this? Where should I store the description data of my items? How to make text content to depend on selected item? 
I have no idea, because I'm totally new at WP and php.

Can anyone please explain the steps?

[image]

Comment: Your question is just to broad, it will require several different things to do, what you want: Knowledge of php and JS at least. Some SQL would be even better. It'll take a lot of time just to code it, forget explain it. Start with something simpler. Throw away WordPress for the time being. It's not for complete beginners.

Comment: I've created exactly what I need using simple JS and HTML/CSS. But now I need to move all this to WordPress. I can't throw it away.

Comment: Well, you could retrieve the data from the database via AJAX and update the front-end accordingly, but as Eugene already said your question is too broad. Try coding something yourself and if you get stuck somewhere then update your question and let us know what the problem is.

Comment: There are still too many ways and a hell lot of configs. You'll likely need custom user tabels in DB to keep your data at least, or even better a separate DB, custom page templates are also very likely. It can even lead to totally self written pages, and inserting them to wordpress is pain in the ass. AJAX is almost 100% needed.

Comment: Well, the main idea of all this headache is giving the customer an opportunity to add a new item to catalog by himself. So I supposed it should look like a number of pages with text content for every item in catalog. So when the customer decides to add new item he just need to make a copy of a page.... The next idea is when I click the arrow in slider, that should provide an AJAX-request and return a certain page. No? But what about the slider? Shall I add it to every content page? Or may be I need to make some page template?

Comment: Not neceserraly, you could make only two page templates, maybe more but not by a lot. Keep all the item descriptions in the database. You don't really need a separate page for each item, you can get item info from DB.

Say make a page temlate that will show all items, and a page template that will show you the item info. The second one will have to show data depending on the selected item from the first page. Something like that, but it's a very rought sketch

Comment: Templates in wordpress  in general are pretty adaptable to suite your needs. The solution to your current problem is not simple. It takes far more then 5 minutes. I'd say about a day of coding at best, and two weeks at worst.

Comment: `I'd say about a day of coding at best, and two weeks at worst` - that's for people who knows php (and I'm not one of them). Anyway thanks for help, I'll try to make it.

Comment: It'll take me about a week of plain coding and at least a week testing and fixing stuff) Sorry). It's not just plain php, there will be AJAX, JS, SQL also. You could do it in plain php i suppose... but it would take about a month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Eugene Anisiutkin and cabrerahector who gave me some ideas about this issue.

For those who are interested, below is the way I've solved my problem.

I've used:

1. [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) v. 5.7.7 plugin,
2. [Custom Post Type UI](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) v. 1.6.0 plugin
3. [slickjs](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) library for slider
4. [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Df3nt4lDT8k&index=4&list=LLcOHBBZmmjAlTmzzFd1tdjg&t=0s) helped me a lot with template files, custom post types and custom fields in WordPress

1) Using Advanced Custom Fields and Custom Post Type UI plugins I've created a post type called `device` and added some custom field such as `deviceUid`, `deviceName` and so on. For each device I've created a post and filled custom fields with data. 
Next step: show all devices on the slider.

2) In my child-theme I've created a file based on `page.php` and called it `page-catalog.php`. This file I'm going to use as a template for my catalog. This template has a loop, inside this loop I get all posts with `type == 'device'`, then I get some custom fields data and show this data inside 'div' element. That gives me a nice 'div' with image and text for every device I have. Each 'div' has an id which is similar to `deviceUid` field data.
Next step: arrange divs to slider and create a WP page for my catalog.

3) In WP-admin panel -> Pages I've created a page called `catalog` and set its template as `page-catalog.php`. Now if I open 'http//:my-site.com/catalog' I would see some divs with image and description data for each device. 
To make this divs look like slider I've used the great slickjs lib. To use it I've first enqueued styles ans scripts for slickjs in my `functions.php` and then initialized my slider as it is said in slickjs documentation.
Next step: connect on slide changed event with AJAX request to show the details of selected device.

4) When I change slide I get the id of the current slide. Using AJAX I send this id to server and I look for a post by custom field data. Then I get all the data from post custom fields and return this data as JSON.
Next step: show json-data in description block.

5) In `success` part of my AJAX request I just append data to description container and style it.

That's all. Now every time I change the slide, I get the new bunch of data for selected device.

Took me almost two weeks and I'm not sure that it's a proper way to resolve the issue but it works for me.